# COGNOS generate report in xls format

Tags: cognos

I have one prompt page, one html report output page and one xls report output page. On prompt page, I have a prompt that selects Output Format(HTML/XLS) and a generate button  that generates the report.  The generate button needs to display the output page in the correct format.

The 'Generate' button just does promptAction('finish'). The thing is that no matter what  i select in the format (XLS,PDF etc),promptAction('finish') always generates the HTML output.
So is there a way to call something like promptAction('finish', varFormat)?

Answer (score 0):

I normally do this the other way around - use native Cognos functionality to run it in the format required (i.e. using run with options). Then use a variable to detect the format that was applied then apply conditional formatting. In your case the would be rendering the XLS page if XLS was selected and render the HTML page if HTML was selected.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this problem with HTML vs PDF page rendering.  I don't have Cognos in front of me but what i found out is that i had to update my conditional style/format because the following would not work right... it was a strange problem but i did come up with a workaround

old pseudo code that wouldnt' work.
Created Variable that says 
    Case RENDER_TYPE 
        When PDF
        THEN PDF
        WHEN HTML
        THEN HTML
    End
then i put on a conditional style using this variable to make the page visible or not... and this would not work.

what i had to do was this...

```
Case 
   When RENDER TYPE = 'HTML'
   Then 'HTML'
   Else 'PDF'  <-  or in your case EXL
End
```

of course its only good for two formats but for some strange reason trying to use any other value than HTML created weird behavior.
Thanks,

If Render Type <> 'HTML' then render PDF otherwise render HTML...

i had problems anytime referring to the render variable with anything other than HTML.   So basically i just had to test when HTML then HTML else other format.